# Assign alias to Month names with Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails application, when a user submits a form, I want to be able to capture the current month and year that the form was created in.  However, for the month, I want to be able to use an alias for a month instead of Rails using the actual month name.  So for example:

- J = January
- F = February
- R = March
- A = April
- M = May
- U = June
- Y = July
- G = August
- S = September
- C = October
- N = November
- D = December

The closest solution I have been able to find it to use the Rails Internationalization (I18n) API.  Does anyone know if there is a better or easier way of doing this rather than creating a fake language to give me localized month names?

**More information**

My intention is for rails to record the new alias in the database under the column month_abbr. Which stands for month abbreviation.  So if I submitted the form in the month of October, the letter "C" would be recorded in the database. Similar to how a timestamp is automatically recorded for each record, I want to capture just the month and record a single character alias.

Peeking further behind the curtain, we need the month abbreviation to be only 1 character.  In the future this month abbreviation will be concatenated into a batch code number. We are trying to keep the batch code number as short as possible, that is why we cannot use the built in month abbreviations.  They are simply too long.

Comment: You have two M's there.

Comment: it's not clear. You want to display the alias? Or accept it as input?

Comment: `U = June`? `G = August`? `Y = July`? `C = October`? This sounds like a terrible idea...

Comment: Why not use the 3-letter abbreviations (Jan, Feb, Mar, ...) that Rails already provides?

Comment: isn't it nonsense? Why do you try to invent the wheel when solution is already there? (see @TomLord's comment)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I apologize about that, it was a typo.  I corrected it now.    Similar to a timestamp, I want rails to record the alias in the database, when a form is submitted.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I wish we could use the built-in month abbreviations.  That would make my life a lot easier.  I plan on concatenating this data to form a batch code number.  My goal is to keep our batch code number as short as possible.  That is why I am trying to figure out how to get rails to record these 1-character aliases instead of a month abbreviation or month number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems easy. Just map the month number to code once at record creation time.

```
class Order
  MONTH_ABBRS = {
    1 => 'J',
    2 => 'F', 
    3 => 'R',
    ...
  }

  before_create :save_month_abbr

  private

  def save_month_abbr
    self.month_abbr = MONTH_ABBRS[created_at.month]
    # also you can create your order number here, or whatever
  end
end
```

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work.  When I save the record, it keeps saving a 0.  When I change `self.month_abbr = MONTH_ABBRS[created_at.month]` to `self.month_abbr = created_at.month`, it records a 10 when the record is saved (which is correct).  I tried your code in the irb and works fine, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the the type of `created_abbr` column?

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't think about that!  month_abbr was set to integer, I changed it to string and it WORKS NOW!  Thank you so much @sergiotulentsev